# Not Queryable field issue

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, dynamic-soql

I have to query on a non-queryable field here. Can someone suggest a workaround for this? Please find my code below.

```
    trigger PM on Account (after update) {
    for ( Account acc : Trigger.New ) {
      List<Product_Metrics_vod__c> listCon = [Select id,Products_vod__r.Name,Account_vod__c from Product_Metrics_vod__c where Account_vod__c =: acc.id];
      List<Account> accs=database.query('SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Restricted_Products_vod__c LIKE' + '\'%'+listCon[0].Products_vod__r.Name +'%\'');
      if (accs.isEmpty() == false) {
            delete listCon;}
    }
}
```

Please note listcon here might have multiple records. We need to search all those Product names in Restricted_Products_vod__c field for the single Account.

Comment: Please note Restricted Product field here contains multiple product names, one of them must be the relevant one as query says here.

Comment: is `account.restricted_products_vod__c` a multi-select field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be careful incase of bulk changes to Accounts. Something like this may be useful to you. I don't know exactly your requirement or your DB schema so you may need to edit slightly.

```
trigger PM on Account (after update) {
    List<Product_Metrics_vod__c> toDelete = new List<Product_Metrics_vod__c>();
    set<id> accsWithChangedRestrictions = new set<id>();
    for(Account acc : trigger.new){
        if(acc.Restricted_Products_vod__c != trigger.oldMap.get(acc.id).Restricted_Products_vod__c)
            accsWithChangedRestrictions.add(acc.id);
    }

    list<Account> accs = [select Restricted_Products_vod__c, (select Products_vod__r.Name from Account_vods__r) from Account where id in :accsWithChangedRestrictions];

    for(Account acc : accs){
        for(Account_vod__c av : acc.Account_vods__r){
            if(acc.Restricted_Products_vod__c.contains(av.Products_vod__r.Name)){
                //found a match
                toDelete.add(av);
            }
        }
    }

    delete toDelete;

}
```

Comment: Thanks Richard. But I am not being able to use it properly. My apologies,it will work I understand. Please note Account is the master, Product_Metrics_vod__c is it's child. Can you please edit it for me?

Comment: Hi Richard, can you please let me know about below line?  Line::  for(Account_vod__c av : acc.Account_vods__r)

Comment: It looks like you have a relationship between Account and Account_Vod__c objects - perhaps called Account_vods__r? I just looped around each one to check the value against the Account.Restricted_Products_vod__c value.

Comment: I was able to do it Richard. Thanks a lot for your help!!! Account_vod__c is the referenced Account Veeva id in TSF